# Prove every subgroup of $A_5$ of order 12 is isomorphic to $A_4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove every subgroup of $A_5$ of order 12 (denoted $H$) is isomorphic to $A_4$.

Attempt:  I can see that there are either one or 4 Sylow 3-group of $H$. But I can't see how that helps the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be a subgroup of $A_{5}$ of order $12$. $A_{5}$ acts transitively on the set of cosets $A_{5}/G$, inducing a map $\rho : A_{5} \to S_{5}$. $\rho$ is injective since $A_{5}$ is simple and the action is not trivial. So $\rho(A_{5})$ is a subgroup of index $2$ in $S_{5}$ and hence it is exactly $A_{5}$ (Seen as permutation groups). $\rho(G)$ is  a subgroup of a subgroup of $A_{5}$ fixing one element (why?) and hence is isomorphic to a subgroup of $A_{4}$. $\rho$ is injective so $\rho(G)$ is isomorphic to $A_{4}$.

Comment: All I can see is $p(G)$ is a subgroup of $A_5$ and $G \cong p(G)$. How do you know it is one element fixed?

Comment: Let $g \in A_{5}$ and assume $g \in G$, then $gG=G$ for all $g \in G$

Comment: ok I see: $A_5/G=[G ,a_1G, a_2G, a_3G, a_4G]$, if $g \in G$, then the first element $G$ is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be transitive: so it's contained in the stabiliser of a point
(good) or in the setwise stabiliser of two points. But I reckon that
latter stabiliser has six elements.

Comment: Can you elaborate what action do you have in mind?